# ABBYY sdk page layout recognition programming

Tags: fonts, character, abbyy

Is there a chance to set users paterns (programe/define) set page layouts ina ABBYY sdk?
Would it be possible to programme minimum size of "text field”that abbyy and set its start (special marking to get specified data from page.
It would be also usefull to have a chance to define a rule to read text fields in a certain order.
Gennerall question would be? Is it possible to mess with layout recognition (word hypothesis analysis, and to choose a range of caracters to be recognized).
Than you for your help. Your product is really the best on the market.
Best regards.
L.

Comment: What product do you use? FRE or FCE? What version? Can you be so kind to describe your questions in details (examples).